# PHP MYSQL- Make use of indexing? Is it possible in this case?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, indexing

My mysql database has the following structure:

[image]

When i run a simple query against it, it takes up to 30 seconds to execute.
The query is -

```
SELECT signinid,photo,first_name,last_name,persontosee,signindate,signintime,isstaff,signouttime,signoutdate,issignedin,companyname,veh_reg 
FROM signin_entries 
WHERE issignedin ='YES' 
AND isstaff='YES'
```

When I run EXPLAIN against this i can see it is processing all 1180 rows, the trouble is columns, photo,signature and qr code all contain base64 encoded strings. (Although in my select statement i am only querying 'photo')

How can i create an Index for this? Is an index even the correct way? Why does it take up to 30 seconds to execute the simple query?

Thankyou for your time

[Explain statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBbX3.png)

Comment: Can you add the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: id select_type table          type   possible_keys key key_len ref   rows     Extra
1    SIMPLE    signin_entries   ALL   staffsignedin  NULL  NULL NULL 1218   Using where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issignedin is a text column. you cannot index text columns. change it to a varchar and add an index.

Comment: Varchar for a status column?

Comment: I don't assume that the author is restricting values to "yes" or "no". if that was the case, I'd recommend a smallint instead or an enum

Comment: assuming that is the case, then I would recommend changing both issignedin and isstaff to smallints, and adding a key that covers both ("alter table signin_entries add key signedin_staff(issignedin, isstaff);")

Comment: Thanks Kae,
Unfortunately i am stuck with 'YES' and 'NO' values

Comment: enum or varchar then

Comment: Never use `varchar` for a value domain of fixed cardinality.

Comment: "Never"?  OP claims to be stuck with YES/NO.  The leaves TEXT (really bad) or VARCHAR or ENUM.  I prefer `ENUM`; others argue against such, leaving `VARCHAR` as the best.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues with your current structure:

- You should use the smallest type possible for columns, e.g. `enum` for columns with some fixed possible values ("yes", "no", "maybe") or an even simpler `boolean` for "yes"/"no" columns.
- You should not store time in `varchar` columns, but `time` or `timestamp`.
- Maybe you should convert the existing `date` columns to `datetime` as you may wish to store the time as well.
- You should not store binary data in the database, unless you have a good reason for that.

After you fixed all issues you can add a combined index over the two columns to improve the execution time further:

```
CREATE INDEX issignedinandstaff ON signin_entries (issignedin, isstaff)
```

Comment: too fast for me! enum should be avoided though, it's pretty inefficient and doesn't hold any real value versus a varchar/boolean/int except maybe space taken on disk on extremely large datasets. If OP doesn't want the time, maybe also suggest to use the `DATE` datatype. +1 either way

Comment: @FMashiro Why do you think `enum` is inefficient? It is basically a `smallint`, you can even use the numerical values. `Varchar` instead is inefficient, because it is indeed a string and should not be used for fixed value ranges.

Comment: Thanks GhostGambler,
Unfortunately im stuck using binary data (base64) as maintaining backup and file locations is an issue, if i take the 'photo' column out of the query the execution of that query is rapid... even with EXPLAIN showing my query is using an index it is still taking a long time.

Comment: How large is the image you stored? An image of 1 MB in size will roughly take 1.37 MB when encoded as Base64. If you have like 100 rows therefore 100 images of 10 MB size you are basically pushing over 1 GB of data from MySQL to PHP… in most (if not all) cases nobody wants to have binary data in the DB. One reason is that the DB is doing nothing good for binary data (no index, no access, no calculations, …), another one is that you keep the DB busy with stuff the file system could do.

Comment: Btw. did you think of image conversion operations, like imagemagicks `convert`? How do you execute the tool on bits stored in a database?

Comment: I am swaying over to now rewriting portion of this application to take the binarydata out of the db and onto the filesystem...it is confidential data though so will have a proper think on how to do this. The table has 1180 rows with multiple binarydata columns and the table is already 580mb.
Thankyou for your help and advice.

Comment: And if you still want to store binary data in mysql you should also use the right type for that: `blob`. Then you do not need base64 anymore, which saves space.

Comment: @FMashiro - `ENUM` is not nearly as inefficient as `TEXT` when testing every row!  Ghost - it is essentially a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (unless more than 255 options).